# OpenProcess second parameter

Tags: windows, winapi

I can't figure out what the second parameter is supposed to do in OpenProcess() (bInheritHandle), I can't find too much info about it and I don't really understand the MDSN page.

My guess is that it takes an handle if it already exists and returns it else opens a new handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`OpenProcess` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess), the second parameter `bInheritHandle` is described as

> If this value is TRUE, processes created by this process will inherit the handle. Otherwise, the processes do not inherit this handle.

I can see how that can be confusing.

What it is trying to describe is that the handle returned by a call to `OpenProcess()` with its `bInheritHandle` parameter set to `TRUE` will be inherited by any child process that your program creates with `CreateProcess()` with its `bInheritHandles` parameter set to `TRUE`, otherwise the handle will not be inherited by new child processes created by your program.

See [Handle Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handle-inheritance) on MSDN for more details.